# $f\in C^{1}$. If $X, f(X)$ are heavy-tailed, so is $\left| f'(X) \ \cdot \ f(X)\right|$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-valued heavy-tailed and continuous random variable with density function $p_X$. Furthermore, let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable.

I am trying to show whether the following assertion is true:

> If $X$ and $f(X)$ are heavy-tailed, so is 
>   \begin{equation}
> \left|f'(X) \ \cdot \ f(X)\right|.
> \end{equation}

To prove heavy-tailedness we need to show that for all $t>0$

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(t \cdot \left|f'(x) \ \cdot \ f(x)\right|\right) \right] 
= \int_{\mathbb R} \exp\left(t \cdot \left|f'(x) \ \cdot \ f(x)\right|\right) \ p_X(x) \ dx = \infty
\end{equation}

Any hints?

Comment: You edited your question and no longer assume $f$ to be Lipschitz - in other words you no longer assume $f'$ to be bounded. Is that really what you wanted?